# Azure - Linux WebApp - Root certificate for chain

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, certificate

I've got my public cer certificates attached to my web app as listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal
The third party have provided both a certificate and root certificate for use.

Our web app is a Linux version - I cant find how to add certificate chain or place the certificate in any location **except** currentuser/my.

Anyone able to help out? Let me know if you need more details. I've hunted this site and there isnt a question thats a duplicate.....

Answer (score 0):

- We can load the Private / root trusted certifacte to Azure Linux from the code

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linuxwindows-containers),use the below code snippet to load a private certificate in a Linux app.

> ```cs
> using System; using System.IO; using
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 
> ... 
> var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("/var/ssl/private/<thumbprint>.p12");
> var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
> // Use the loaded certificate
> ```

Add ***`WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`*** in Application Settings under the Configuration Section of the deployed Azure Linux Web App

[image]

Please refer [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/)  ,[Root CA on App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/06/22/Root-CA-on-App-Service-Guide.html) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760903/deploying-net-core-3-linux-container-on-azure-web-app-container-with-identityse) for more information

Comment: I've already done this - trouble is because I cant set the root certificate in the right trusted store - it comes up with: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
I see i can setup an ASE but wanted to work around it - doesnt seem possible though via the worker server. Azure must be locking down for security reasons.

Comment: As mentioned by @SnehaAgarwal-MSFT, there are some limitations to add root trusted certificate. Please refer [Ms Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/107132/adding-trust-to-root-certificate-store-on-an-app-s.html)